Regex sub() to replace only section of pattern
Can you use sub() to replace only a specific section of the pattern matched?
so in this example, i want to look for all cases where an ellipse is in between letters/numbers and add a space after the ellipse.
input = "hello...world"

output = "hello... world"

what to change from: sub(r'\w\.\.\.\w', "... ", input)

Have you tried using lookahead/lookbehind: re.sub(r'(?<=\w)\.\.\.(?=\w)', "... ", input)

You can match with \w\.\.\.(?=\w) and replace with \g<0>  See https://regex101.com/r/FbhkK4/1

You could assert a word character directly to the right, and use the full match in the replacement denoted by \g<0>
\w\.\.\.(?=\w)

In the replacement use the full match followed by a space.
\g<0> 
See a regex demo and a Python demo.
Example
import re

pattern = r"\w\.\.\.(?=\w)"
s = "hello...world"
result = re.sub(pattern, r"\g<0> ", s,)

if result:
    print (result)

Output
hello... world

Another option is using 2 capture groups:
(\w\.\.\.)(\w)

Then in the replacement using both capture groups with a space in between:
\1 \2
See another regex demo
